# Android ¿Como modificar el contenido de un Drawer Menu desde un Fragment?

Tags: android

Buen día.

Tengo un activity con un drawer menu que tiene unas secciones, lo que quiero hacer es modificar el texto de esas secciones desde un fragment, pero no se como se debería crear la instancia en mi fragment para poder modificar el contenido de  mi drawer menu.

De antemano gracias.

Aqui mi fragment.

```
public class ActionFragment extends Fragment {

private Button btnCambiarTexto;

public ActionFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_action, container, false);

    btnCambiarTexto = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCambiarTexto);

    btnCambiarTexto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //al presionar cambiar texto de la seccion email, que aparece en la cabecera del drawer menu
        }
    });

    return v;
}}
```

aqui mi drawer menu (Activity)

```
public class LeftMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private TextView txtSearchToolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_left_menu);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //seleccionamos por defecto la primera opcion del menu
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
    onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));

}}
```

Comment: " modificar el texto de esas secciones desde un fragment" pero como lo realizarías desde un fragment, me refiero a dar click en un boton dentro de un fragment? podrías dar mas datos.

Comment: Hola Elenasys, es como dijiste, por ejemplo si le doy click a un boton dentro del fragment, entonces cambie el texto de la seccion que yo requiera cambiar.

Comment: He agregado una respuesta, en realidad es sencillo, pero podrías agregar tu código para indicar exactamente donde realizar los cambios.

Comment: Código de mi fragment agregado.

Comment: y donde construyes el menú?

Comment: En mi activity principal

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47999/discussion-between-devjav-and-elenasys).

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar la actualización de los elementos dentro de un Drawer menu simplemente tienes que actualizar el `Adapter` con los nuevos datos y al final asignar el `Adapter` con los nuevos datos a tu menú.

```
 //Notifica actualización de datos.
 myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 //Asigna adapter.
 mDrawerList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: Como siempre Jorge un grande